# Why do we take antibiotics if our immune system already produces them?

Tags: immunology, antibiotics, immune-system, immunoglobin, antibiotic-resistance

Why do we take antibiotics if our immune system already produces them? Is it because our body doesnt make enough or the specific complementary antibody to fit with the antigen?

Comment: Perhaps you could respond to the answers — or this comment — to clarify whether you were really confusing antibiotics and antibodies, or whether you were interested in "innate immunity".

Answer (score 1):

Since people and animals routinely get sick, it is obvious that our immune system (which includes but isn't limited to antibodies) doesn't always protect against pathogens.  There are many reasons for this, far too many to summarize here, but one common reason is that it takes several days for the adaptive part of the immune system (which includes antibodies, among other things) to gear up and control an infection. Therefore, early treatment with antibiotics can help limit an infection before the immune system is fully engaged.

Pathogenic bacteria are often resistant to immunity in many ways as well; that's one of the adaptations that makes them pathogenic. That means that even later in an infection, antibiotics can supplement the immune response and help eliminate bacteria.  Note that many antibiotics require a functional immune system to be completely effective.

Answer (score 0):

I assume from your question (and your pseudonym) that you are confused by terminology. Our adaptive immune system does **not** make *antibiotics*, it makes *antibodies*. [Antibiotics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibiotics) are small molecules that interfere with bacterial metabolism. [Antibodies](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Antibody) are proteins that recognise foreign macromolecules. (You could regard both as *“anti-bacterials”* — perhaps this is what you were thinking of — but the immune system is not restricted to recognizing bacteria.)

We take antibiotics when we have an infection from bacteria that have evaded the immune system.

Comment: This isn't true. We do make antimicrobial peptides, which are essentially antibiotics.

Comment: @MattDMo The immune system makes antibiotics? I answered the question at the level it was asked. We are dealing with a first poster who is unfamiliar with scientific terms. We do not help him or anyone else by muddying our answers with esotericism.

Comment: Questions are simply a vehicle for producing answers. Remember, the point of Stack Exchange is not to answer an OP's specific question *just* for the OP, it is to produce a lasting repository of knowledge. If you're going to make an answer, make it an *accurate, complete* answer. Besides, antimicrobial peptides (AMPs) are not "esoteric" - they're a vital part of the innate immune system.

Comment: @mattdmo To be strictly fair, David is correct since the original definition of an antibiotic was that it was s substance made by bacteria and fungi. But the internet and non scientific use, progress, and synthetic antibacterial agents has invalidated the original definition.

Comment: So sulfonamides were not initially called antibiotics, but antibacterial agents because they were synthetic.

Comment: Methinks thou dost protest too much. But if I am wrong, retitle the question  something like immunity and antibiotics, rewrite it, and supply your answer. Because if you don't nobody will benefit from your contribution as they'll assume that it's a naive question that really should be pulled.

Comment: The op isn't involved in the discussion

Comment: @GrahamChiu  Op?

Comment: I give a short straightforward answer to an obvious misunderstanding and someone marks it down. OK.I'll make it less comprehensible by qualifying it, then will that person mark me up again. In my dreams! What's wrong with you guys?

Answer (score 0):

We take antibiotics when our own immune system is insufficient to control infections. We do make antibiotics as localized defence systems

> Defensins and cathelicidins belong to antimicrobial peptides (AMP), called also the natural antibiotics. They are found in Prokaryotes and Eukaryotes, also are synthesized in plants. These molecules were described in bacteria, invertebrates, vertebrates, also in mammals including humans.

But clearly these  can be overwhelmed by bacteria resistant to their action, or by overwhelming rates of reproduction of invading bacteria

http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC3487008/

Our mammalian physiology has further evolved the innate immune system, and the adaptive immune system to cope with invasions that bypass these simple non-adaptive molecular defenses.

Comment: Please provide a citation for your quote.